# Subdomain with port number in Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

Tags: subdomain

I have created subdomain in my DNS server. How can I set each subdomain so that it only accepts connections via a particular port?

For example: ftp.example.com → only accepts connections that come from port 21

Answer (score 0):

You can set port restrictions using [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables).

You can also set port restrictions on the server itself and it depends on your server architecture. If you're running [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server), then you should take a look at defining a virtual host (vhost).

Just for illustration sake:

```
<VirtualHost *:21>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        ServerName ftp.example.com

        # Index + Directory root
        DirectoryIndex index.php | index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/path/to/site
</VirtualHost>
```

See that "*:21" - that's the port number.

Generally speaking, *ftp.example.com* would probably still redirect to your server's root directory.